# Can't find Click the Continue button to proceed with the payment in translation string

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, translation

I can't find *Click the Continue button to proceed with the payment.* from a Contribute form in the translation strings even if I can find other strings from that Contribute form. It's untranslated in my language and I'd like to fix it. The string changer does nothing.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string has html in it: `Click the <strong>Continue</strong> button to proceed with the payment`. e.g. https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/blob/f0d769640f51dd1fe891963e4208bffd7625da91/po/it_IT/common-base.po#L12259

If you're trying to use word replacements, you would need to include that when doing a word replacement, except there are some bugs in that when using html which are still being worked on (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15836)

Comment: Thanks @demerit: with your help I found the correct string. I'm keeping a custom translation so I don't have to use workarounds! I will eventually update the online translation.